# Vue.js How to mirror input field with v-model and computed property and a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to figure out how to properly mirror two input fields and dynamically change them based on a checkbox value. This is the best what I can think of using computed property with get and set features.
The problem is when the user types (1)"ABC" in shipping details, (2)unchecks (copy_chekcbox=false), (3)types "123" in billing details, and (4)checks back (copy_chekcbox=true) (5)the billing details doesn't revert to shipping details, which is what I need.
[Image with steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bA7U.png)

Also, is there any shorter and more optimal way to mirror two fields and change their values based on checkbox value?

Thank you in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">

    <p>Shipping details</p>
    <input v-model="shipping" type="text" />

    <p>Same as shipping: <input type="checkbox" v-model="copy_chekcbox" /></p>

    <p>Billing details</p>
    <input v-model="billing" type="text" :disabled="copy_chekcbox" />

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        shipping_data: '',
        billing_data: '',
        copy_chekcbox: true,
      },
      computed: {
        shipping: {
          get: function() {
            return this.shipping_data
          },
          set: function(newValue) {
            if (!this.copy_chekcbox) {
              this.shipping_data = newValue
            } else {
              this.billing_data = newValue
              this.shipping_data = newValue
            }
          },
        },
        billing: {
          get: function() {
            return this.billing_data
          },
          set: function(newValue) {
            if (!this.copy_chekcbox) {
              this.billing_data = newValue
            } else {
              this.billing_data = this.shipping_data
            }
          },
        },
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just to mention you have a typo in copy_checkbox :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion I think the easiest way is use two inputs with v-if:

```html
<p>Shipping details</p>
<input v-model="shipping" type="text">

<p>Same as shipping: <input type="checkbox" v-model="copy_chekcbox"></p>

<p>Billing details</p>

<template v-if="copy_chekcbox">
  <input v-model="shipping" type="text">
<template>
<template v-else>
  <input v-model="billing" type="text">
</template>
```

The main advantage of this method is that your JavaScript code remains simple.

Comment: Thank you! This is a really simple and elegant approach and solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
billing: {
          get: function() {
            return this.copy_checkbox ? this.shipping_data : this.billing_data
          },
```

it should rerun the computed function for your billing data when you change copy_checkbox and thus update your billing_data.

Comment: Well, the problem is that value changes only in the browser, but not in the vue.js data property: https://i.imgur.com/yGjgKX1.png

Comment: if you want to have it changed in your data you should use a `watch` on `copy_checkbox`
and if changed to true set `billin_data` to `shipping_data`. 
also add a second `watch` to `shipping_data` that if `copy_checkbox` is set also updates your `billing_data`. 

In that case you could completely remove your 2 computed properties.